# K-means:Updaing centroids successively after each addition

Tags: k-means

Say we have five data points A,B,C,D,E and we are using K-means clustering algorithm to cluster them into two clusters.Can we update the centroids as follow:

Let's select first two i.e. A,B as centroids of initial clusters.
Then calculate the distance of C from A as well as from B.Say C is nearer to A.
Update the centroid of cluster with centroid A before the next step i.e. now new centroids are (A+C)/2 and B.
Then calculate the distances of D from these new centroids and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it seems like we can update centroids incrementally in k-means as explained in chapter 8 of  **"Introduction to Data Mining" by Kumar**. Here is the actual text:

> #### Updating Centroids Incrementally
>
> Instead of updating cluster centroids after all points have been assigned to a cluster, the centroids can be updated incrementally, after each assignment of a point to a cluster. Notice that this requires either zero or two updates to cluster centroids at each step, since a point either moves to a new cluster (two updates) or stays in its current cluster (zero updates). Using an incremental update strategy guarantees that empty clusters are not produced since all clusters start with a single point, and if a cluster ever has only one point, then that point will always be reassigned to the same cluster.
>
> In addition, if incremental updating is used, the relative weight of the point
> being added may be adjusted; e.g., the weight of points is often decreased as
> the clustering proceeds. While this can result in better accuracy and faster
> convergence, it can be difficult to make a good choice for the relative weight, especially in a wide variety of situations. These update issues are similar to those involved in updating weights for artificial neural networks.
>
> Yet another benefit of incremental updates has to do with using objectives
> other than “minimize SSE.” Suppose that we are given an arbitrary objective
> function to measure the goodness of a set of clusters. When we process an
> individual point, we can compute the value of the objective function for each
> possible cluster assignment, and then choose the one that optimizes the objective. Specific examples of alternative objective functions are given in Section 8.5.2.
>
> On the negative side, updating centroids incrementally introduces an order dependency. In other words, the clusters produced may depend on the order in which the points are processed. Although this can be addressed by
> randomizing the order in which the points are processed, the basic K-means
> approach of updating the centroids after all points have been assigned to clusters has no order dependency. Also, incremental updates are slightly more
> expensive. However, K-means converges rather quickly, and therefore, the
> number of points switching clusters quickly becomes relatively small.